# How to start a process in jbpm 7.0 using remote api

Tags: json, jbpm

I am trying to start a process a process which is already deployed in my jbpm workbench (jbpm 7.0.0) using remote api but the api client shows 404 error code.Can someone please tell me how to use remote api to start a process in jbpm 7.0.0.

Comment: Can you tell more information - what you tried so far. Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter your link to MCVE is broken :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve thank you